# How can I set amount field to PayPal SDK

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on PayPal express and want to send the amount field value to the server file (payment.php)
from the client-side script and also want to gets its value to the server-side file.

Here is client-side script

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<client-id>"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function() {
          return fetch('payment.php', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
          }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
          }).then(function(data) {
            return data.id;
          });
        },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
          window.location = "paypal-transaction-complete.php?&orderID="+data.orderID;             
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
```

Here is the payment.php where I want to get the amount field value

```
<?php

namespace Sample\CaptureIntentExamples;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//1. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side SDK`.
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;
require 'paypal-client.php';
class CreateOrder
{
  public static function createOrder($debug=false)
  {
    $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
    $request->prefer('return=representation');
    $request->body = self::buildRequestBody();
   // 3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    return $response;
  }

    private static function buildRequestBody()
    {
        return array(
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
            'application_context' =>
                array(
                    'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
                    'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel'
                ),
            'purchase_units' =>
                array(
                    0 =>
                        array(
                            'amount' =>
                                array(
                                    'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                    'value' => '20.00'
                                )
                        )
                )
        );
    }
}
if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
  CreateOrder::createOrder(true);
}
?>
```

Please let me know how can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP the simplest way is going to be to use a GET string.

```
return fetch('payment.php?amount=' + document.getElementById('amount').value , {
```

^ You might want to validate or sanitize that input or URL encode the value, but for the most part it should work.

```
                            array(
                                'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                'value' => $_GET['amount']
                            )
```

It's not modern but that's PHP for you, parsing JSON is probably overkill.

---

You shouldn't be using `actions.order.capture()` when creating on the server, I'd be surprised if that even works. Implement a capture order route on your server, and use this JS sample that has proper error handling: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server